# Getting the Content of a ContentControl Field as RichText

Tags: ms-word, openxml

i am trying to create a Word Template, where Users put in notes with basic formating options (like Bullet List , indentations etc.). But i need that content as Richtext, to display it in a browser.
I thought the RichText ContentControl field would save its content as.. well Richtext. But it turns out to be ooxml.
Is there maybe some converter to convert a richtext field to actual richtext?

Currently its content looks like this:

```
<w:sdtContent>
                <w:p>
                    <w:pPr>
                        <w:pStyle w:val="Listenabsatz" />
                        <w:ind w:left="4320" />
                    </w:pPr>
                    <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart" />
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>Ztzjtzj</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd" />
                </w:p>
                <w:p>
                    <w:pPr>
                        <w:pStyle w:val="Listenabsatz" />
                        <w:ind w:left="4320" />
                    </w:pPr>
                    <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart" />
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>Tzjtzjtzj</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd" />
                </w:p>
 </w:sdtContent>
```

Comment: just to be sure - you need to do this without using the Word object model (i.e. the Microsoft.Word object)?

Comment: Yea, as far as i know MsWord needs to be installed for that solution to be working. And since the code should run on a linux server, that seems not very optimal.  I am currently using python to open the docx as archive, get the document.xml and parse that how i need it. And my in-browser-editor saves as html.... so i try to translate between xml and this html (seemed to be easier than richtext to xml).

Comment: not html.  i ment Json.